# I am getting a POST 500 (Internal Server Error) "Too few arguments to function" in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I do not know what I am missing, but I cant make this work. It's throwing an error, POST 500 (Internal Server Error) "Too few arguments to function" in Laravel.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnUpdateStudent', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                   }
            });
    $td=$(this).closest('td');
    $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
    var id=$td.attr("data-studId");
    var inputEditName="<input type='text' class='inputEditName form-control'>";
    $tr.find('td:eq(1)').val(inputEditName);
    $tr.find('td:eq(1)').find("input.inputEditName").val();
    var inputEditEmail="<input type='text' class='inputEditEmail form-control'>";
    $tr.find('td:eq(2)').val(inputEditEmail);
    $tr.find('td:eq(2)').find("input.inputEditEmail").val();
    var options = $('#selectDepartment option');
    var optionValues = $.map(options ,function(option){
        return "<option value='"+option.value+"'>"+option.text+"</option>";});
    var selectDepartment ="<select class='selectDepartment form-select form-control'></select>";
    var updateDept=$('.selectDepartment').val();
    $tr.find('td:eq(3)').val(selectDepartment);
    $tr.find('td:eq(3)').find("select.selectDepartment").html(optionValues);
    $tr.find('td:eq(3)').find("selectDepartment").val();
    $tr.find('td:eq(3)').find("select.selectDepartment").val(updateDept);
    var editname=$tr.find('td:eq(1)').find("input.inputEditName").val();
    var editemail=$tr.find('td:eq(2)').find("input.inputEditEmail").val();
    var editdepartment=$tr.find('td:eq(3)').find("select.selectDepartment").val();
    var data = {
             'id' : id,
             'name' : editname,
             'email': editemail,
             'department_id': editdepartment
            }
    
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/update-student",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status == 400) {
                $('#saveform_errList').html("");
                $('#saveform_errList').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values){
                    $('#saveform_errList').append('<li>'+err_values+'</li>');
                });
               
                }else {
                    $('#saveform_errList').html("");
                    $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-success')
                    $('#success_message').text(response.message)
                    $("#inputForm").find('input').val("");
                }

            }
            
        });

    });
```

this is my controller. did i missed something? or is there part that should be there?

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'=> 'required|max:100',
            'email'=>'required|email|max:100',
            'department_id'=>'required'
        ]);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>400,
                'errors'=>$validator->messages()
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $student = Student::find();
            
            if($student)
            
            {
                $student->id = $request->input('id');
                $student->name = $request->input('name');
                $student->email = $request->input('email');
                $student->department_id = $request->input('department_id');
                $student->update();
                
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=>200,
                    'message'=>'Student Updated Successfully.'
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=>404,
                    'message'=> 'No Student Found.'
                ]);
            }
        }      
    }
```

I tried reviewing my code but I really can't distinguish the problem. I need help

Comment: Somewhere you are using a function with too few arguments. Maybe here: `$student = Student::find();`

Comment: aight, what should i do to fix it?

Comment: Check if `Student::find()` requires some parameter. If yes, that is the error and to fix it you need to pass required parameter(s), or use an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$student = Student::find()` is where your issue is. The find() method requires one parameter which is the primary key `id` gotten from your database.

Now, since you already passed the `id` via your ajax just change your code to this:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'=> 'required|max:100',
            'email'=>'required|email|max:100',
            'department_id'=>'required'
        ]);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>400,
                'errors'=>$validator->messages()
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $student = Student::find($request->id); // here I have added the required parameter
            
            if($student)
            
            {
                $student->id = $request->input('id');
                $student->name = $request->input('name');
                $student->email = $request->input('email');
                $student->department_id = $request->input('department_id');
                $student->update();
                
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=>200,
                    'message'=>'Student Updated Successfully.'
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=>404,
                    'message'=> 'No Student Found.'
                ]);
            }
        }      
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
To refresh the page automatically after the `Ajax` request is successful, do this:
Add this directly above where you have `if (response.status == 400) {`:

```
if (response.status == 200) {
location.reload();
}
```

This will reload the page automatically.

Comment: last question, i still need to click the refresh button so that the changes would reflect. what should i do?

Comment: What refresh button?

Comment: Oh you mean your browser?

Comment: yes, whenever i add delete or update i need to click the browser's refresh button

Comment: You did not put a handler in your ```Ajax``` request that checks whether the delete was successful.

Comment: @MeepoTheNewbie I have updated my answer with a solution to that.